# Merge with only 'when matched then update' In Oracle 9i

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle9i

I am working at a company with Oracle 9i 9.2, and I am unable to upgrade.

A merge which only does an update on matched, not an insert on not-matched, seems not to work in this version.

I am trying to do:

```
MERGE INTO CDLREFWORK.pricing d --table to insert to 
   USING    V_REC  S  --table source 
   ON ( D.item_id = S.item_id
        and   d.line_type = s.line_type
        AND d.price_code =s.price_code )
   WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET
    d.APPLICATION_ID='CPMASI',
    d.SYS_UPDATE_DATE=SYSDATE,
    d.OPERATOR_ID=nvl(s.OPERATOR_ID,  d.OPERATOR_ID),
    d.LOCATION_ID=nvl(s.LOCATION_ID,d.LOCATION_ID),
    d.ITEM_ID= nvl(s.ITEM_ID,d.ITEM_ID),
    d.LINE_TYPE= nvl(s. LINE_TYPE, d.LINE_TYPE),
    d.EXPIRATION_DATE=nvl(s.EXPIRATION_DATE,d.EXPIRATION_DATE),
    d.PRICE_CODE= nvl(s.PRICE_CODE,d.PRICE_CODE),
    d.TO_QTY=nvl(s.TO_QTY,d.TO_QTY),
    d.PRICE= nvl(s.PRICE,d.PRICE),
    d.CHARGE_CODE=nvl(s.CHARGE_CODE,d.CHARGE_CODE),
    d.SOC=nvl(s.SOC,d.SOC), 
    d.COMMITMENT=nvl(s.COMMITMENT,d.COMMITMENT), 
    d.CAMBIAZO_CODE=nvl(s.CAMBIAZO_CODE,d.CAMBIAZO_CODE),  
    d.PPG_IND=nvl(s.PPG_IND,d.PPG_IND);
```

This gets:

```
SQL Error: ORA-00905: missing keyword
00905. 00000 -  "missing keyword"
```

If this isn't possible in 9i, then how would I do an equivalent update instead?

Comment: [The syntax diagram for 9i](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96540/statements_915a.htm) shows that you had to have both `when matched` and `when not matched` clauses. [That changed in 10gR1](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/statements_9016.htm) (and is mentioned in the [new features](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/wnsql.htm) list)..

Comment: Hello Alex.  Please remember I can not upgrade

Comment: Alex. you win!!

Comment: but  there is not option to vote for you @AlexPoole

Comment: [See the help centre](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). I'm not sure if winning means my answer solves your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The syntax diagram for 9i](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96540/statements_915a.htm) shows that you had to have both `when matched` and `when not matched` clauses. [That changed in 10gR1](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/statements_9016.htm) (and is mentioned in the [new features](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/wnsql.htm) list); but that doesn't really help you if you can't upgrade - it just explains why it doesn't work. You were also trying to update two of the three columns from the join clause, which isn't allowed.

You can do a correlated update instead:

```
UPDATE CDLREFWORK.pricing d
SET (d.APPLICATION_ID, d.SYS_UPDATE_DATE, d.OPERATOR_ID, d.LOCATION_ID,
  d.EXPIRATION_DATE, d.PRICE_CODE, d.TO_QTY, d.PRICE, d.CHARGE_CODE, d.SOC,
  d.COMMITMENT, d.CAMBIAZO_CODE, d.PPG_IND)
= (
  SELECT 'CPMASI',
    SYSDATE,
    nvl(s.OPERATOR_ID,  d.OPERATOR_ID),
    nvl(s.LOCATION_ID,d.LOCATION_ID),
    nvl(s.EXPIRATION_DATE,d.EXPIRATION_DATE),
    nvl(s.PRICE_CODE,d.PRICE_CODE),
    nvl(s.TO_QTY,d.TO_QTY),
    nvl(s.PRICE,d.PRICE),
    nvl(s.CHARGE_CODE,d.CHARGE_CODE),
    nvl(s.SOC,d.SOC), 
    nvl(s.COMMITMENT,d.COMMITMENT), 
    nvl(s.CAMBIAZO_CODE,d.CAMBIAZO_CODE),  
    nvl(s.PPG_IND,d.PPG_IND)
  FROM V_REC s
  WHERE s.item_id =d.item_id
  AND s.line_type = d.line_type
  AND s.price_code = d.price_code
)
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT null
  FROM V_REC s
  WHERE s.item_id =d.item_id
  AND s.line_type = d.line_type
  AND s.price_code = d.price_code
);
```

I've taken out the `item_id` and `line_type` columns as you already know they match. The `where exists` clause means only rows in `pricing` which actually have a matching row in `v_rec` are updated. That *may* mean the `nvl()` calls are redundant, and you just need to select the value from `s`, but without knowing your data it's hard to be sure.